# How to call and access arguments for a function that has colon separated parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a python function that computes the number of minutes given the days, hours and minutes.

The function is to be called

```
def minutes(d:'days', h:'hours', m:'minutes'):
```

I'm confused as to how to assign numerical values to the `d`, `h`, and `m` so I can then manipulate those variables. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are reinventing the wheel? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: i'm just trying to familiarize myself with basic python variable types, and was confused to see a dictionary type structure as the parameter to a function.. @mgsk

Comment: The colons are not a dictionary structure, they are [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function  is using  python3 [function annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations):

You can still just pass args like you normally would:

```
def minutes(d:'days', h:'hours', m:'minutes'):
    print(minutes.__annotations__ )
    print(d,h,m)
print(minutes(10,10,10)

{'d': 'days', 'm': 'minutes', 'h': 'hours'}
10 10 10
```

Or pass a dict:

```
dic = {"d":22,"h":12,"m":25}
print(minutes(**dic))  
{'d': 'days', 'm': 'minutes', 'h': 'hours'}
22 12 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a job for a `namedtuple` (part of the `collections` library). A `collections.namedtuple` allows you to access the different members of the tuple by names you have given them.

Example:

```
# import the namedtuple module from the library
from collections import namedtuple as nt
# create a type of namedtuple called Time that contains days, hours, minutes
Time = nt('Time', 'days hours minutes')
# you can make a Time instance this way
t1 = Time(0, 0, 1)
# now you can print it to see what's inside
print(t1) # Time(days=0, hours=0, minutes=1)
# ...and access the parts of the Time object by name
print(t1.minutes) # 1
# ...or access them by index
print(t1[2]) # 1
```

Now to convert to minutes you can simply do this:

```
from collections import namedtuple as nt
Time = nt('Time', 'days hours minutes')
def minutes(d: 'days', h: 'hours', m: 'minutes'):
    t = Time(d, h, m)
    return t.days*24*60 + t.hours*60 + t.minutes

#testing
assert minutes(1,1,1) == 24*60 + 60 + 1
```

Or you could also change your desired function signature a bit, and do it this way which seems a little more straight forward:

```
def minutes(t: 'time'):
    return t.days*24*60 + t.hours*60 + t.minutes

#testing
t = Time(1,1,1)
assert minutes(t) == 24*60 + 60 + 1
```

EDIT: Didn't realize the point of the question was to understand what the colons are doing. The colons and strings following the arguments in the function signature are not a dictionary; they are [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), which I believe are new in Python 3.